# Codeigniter sessions, multiple with varying lengths

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have an upload website, currently when someone uploads something as a guest they have a session that lets them edit that uploads title for 5mins then it expires.

I've just added login to the website unrelated to the upload part (atm) but since i set the CI session expire to 300ms (5 minutes) the system logs the user out after that time.

I'd like them to stay logged in for 24hours. Note also that i have sessions on autoload.

Can anyone advise what's bes to go about this? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the upload time in the database along with the other upload data, such as the filename, size, etc., and use it to limit the edit time.

If you're not using a database to store info about this files, you can use a file based solution (much slower) or have a session variable to store the upload time (wich I think you already have, if not create one) and check the time on the edit page against this variable. If it is greater the the time limit you want, clear it and don't mess with the login data.